# Função não retira os elementos do array

Tags: php, javascript

Dentro do `PHP` eu adiciono dois `arrays` e depois eu adiciono eles em uma variavel de um `print` com JS.

```
<?php
$objp = array();    
$objs = array();

print("<SCRIPT language=javascript> 
         objp = \"$objp\";
         objs = \"$objs\";
         n_p = new Array (10);
         </SCRIPT>");   
?>
```

Agora dentro do `JavaScript` eu utilizo um for quando eu submeto para adicionar o conteúdo desses dois `arrays` dentro do `n_p`;

```
<script language="javascript">

    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if(objp!=''){
            n_p[i] = objp;
            objp.shift();
        }
        else{
            n_p[i] = objs;
            objs.shift();
        }   
    }
</script>
```

O problema é: Estou utilizando o `shift()` para remover o primeiro elemento do `array`, mas quando ele entra dentro do `if` ele não executa. Qual pode ser o problema?
A função `objs.shift();` não é executada!

Obs* Utilizei o [splice()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) mas acabou não funcionando também!

Comment: `language="javascript"` está descontinuado, deve ser `type="text/javascript"` ou pode não levar nada em determinados tipos de documento.

Comment: @Zuul editei da maneira que você mostrou, mas acabou não resolvendo também. Mas agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Na verdade não era bem uma ajuda para o teu problema atual mas sim um aviso sobre os standards :) O @bfavaretto está no bom caminho para te resolver a questão!

Comment: O que acontece é simples... Se você tá comparando o array objp com nada e ele tiver alguma coisa vai retornar falso. rsrs. Óbvio né. Se você quer checar se o primeiro local está vazio você deve comparar o identificador do primeiro espaço: if (objp[0] != '')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suas variáveis `objp` e `objs` no JavaScript não são arrays, são strings. O PHP vai simplesmente emitir `"Array()"` para elas. O seu PHP precisaria ser assim:

```
print("<SCRIPT language=javascript> 
     objp = " . json_encode($objp) . ";
     objs = " . json_encode($objs) . ";
     n_p = new Array (10);
     </SCRIPT>");
```

Supondo que entendi o que você pretende com o loop em JavaScript, ele deveria ficar assim:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if(objp[i] != ''){
        n_p[i] = objp[i];
        objp.splice(i, 1);
    }
    else{
        n_p[i] = objs[i];
        objs.splice(i, 1);;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Obrigado @bfavaretto não conhecia esse método! Mas da mesma maneira, o `for` no `JS` não executa após o `if();` para ser mais exato, ele não executa a função `objp.shift();`

Comment: Fiz uma edição incluindo modificações no JS. Veja se é isso.

Comment: agradeço pela edição @bfavaretto, mas não chegou a funcionar mesmo assim, pelo visto está sendo um erro do mozilla. Mas enquanto ao caso de sua edição, o `i` que está sendo como contador poderia pegar o próximo elemento do `array`, ou seja se o contador do primeiro `array` chegar a `3` e conter algum `elemento` na primeira posição do `objs` poderia dar erro!

Comment: Você pode explicar melhor o que está tentando fazer?

Comment: Simplesmente estou adicionando aos `arrays` o valor encontrado de um `select` e adicionando ao `n_p` para passar ao próximo programa! **Obs** é necessário eu fazer isso para efetuar uma outra pesquisa no próximo, mas isso é facultativo.

Comment: Mas ainda não entendi como a nova array será construída a partir das outras duas. O que cada uma delas pode conter? Os tamanhos são sempre os mesmos? Seria melhor resolver isso direto no PHP, e passar a array já pronta pro JavaScript (a menos que você também for usar as duas originais no JS).

Comment: Olha o que eu comentei na sua publicação..