# É possível rodar uma função JavaScript pelo PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Eu quero rodar uma função do `JavaScript` sem "submete-lo", ou seja quando a tela for acessada o `php` vai chamar a função `JavaScript` e rodar o que tem nela e depois continuar o código normal. É possível?
**Obs:** A função contém dados que só rodam no `JavaScript`!

Meu objetivo é Rodar esse trecho:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if(objp!=''){           
            n_p[i] = 'P' + objp[0];
            objp.splice(0,1);
        }
        else{
            n_p[i] = 'S' + objs[0];
            objs.splice(0,1);
        }   
    }
</script>
//No PHP
```

Para melhor entendimento do trecho acima seguir [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35535/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-n%C3%A3o-retira-os-elementos-do-array/35536#35536)

Comment: Explique melhor o seu objetivo, pode ter uma outra forma de fazer isto. Se eu entendi o que você quer De uma maneira geral não dá para fazer isto diretamente. Talvez até seja possível fazer alguma **gambiarra** com algum *engine* JS, mas eu preferia achar outra solução.

Comment: Tu pode rodar javascript no lado do servidor utilizando node.js por exemplo. Talvez seja um caminho viável para o seu problema.

Comment: Você pode colocar o trecho HTML acima em um bloco na página PHP dentro de um condicional IF, por exemplo, e renderizá-lo de acordo com seus requisitos.

Comment: Mas no meu caso @OnoSendai, o meu trecho acima roda em php? Pois sinceramente pelo pouco tempo que estou nessa linguagem, ainda não vi esse código rodar em um bloco php!

Comment: @dap.tci, como seria esse método? Desculpe-me, mas eu desconheço isso!

Comment: Agora que você adicionou o trecho de código que quer rodar, acredito que node.js não seja a melhor opção. Por que você não faz esse loop com esses tratamentos em PHP e depois passa para o javascript essas variáveis (`objp` e `objs`) já prontas para serem utilizadas?

Comment: @Alexandre O código JS não será executado no PHP - apenas sua emissão será controlada pelo PHP. Assim: <?php if ($mostrar) { ?>Conteúdo HTML<?php } ?>. Não sei se a sintaxe é viável (Não sou especialista em PHP), mas o controle de fluxo seria assim.

Comment: Tem como adaptar esse trecho no PHP? Pois ai no caso eu só adiciono depois no JS'

Comment: Além de explicar o que quer fazer com o código, explique o que está acontecendo na interface, o que a página faz em resposta a qual ação do usuário. . . . Por favor, em vez de ficar esclarecendo coisas aqui nos comentários, clique no link **[edit]** abaixo da pergunta e acrescente **nela** as novas informações.

Comment: PHP -> Lado servidor, JS -> Lado cliente. Precisa BEM entender a diferença!

Comment: Alexandre, na minha resposta à sua pergunta anterior eu já havia pedido mais detalhes sobre o que você está tentando fazer: o que as arrays contêm (no PHP), e o que a array mesclada deve conter. Tudo indica que você deve resolver no PHP e passar a array pronta pro JS, mas ninguém vai conseguir te ajudar sem esses detalhes. Favor [edit] sua pergunta para incluí-los. Obrigado.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## PHP não sabe JavaScript

O PHP não pode chamar diretamente uma função JavaScript porque o PHP é interpretado no lado do servidor.

O PHP não vê um código ali, ele simplesmente copia o texto caractere a caractere e envia para o navegador do usuário.

## O navegador sabe JavaScript

Quando o navegador lê os dados recebidos já em HTML, ele começa a interpretar esse HTML e montar os elementos na tela.

Ao encontrar uma tag `<script>` o nevegador pára o que está fazendo e executa o que tiver nesse script.

Note que, neste ponto, o navegador está executando o script no computador do usuário, enquanto o PHP (que possivelmente já terminou de executar) estava rodando no servidor.

## Executar código no carregamento da página

Então, para todo efeito, o código citado na pergunta será executado no navegador exatamente no momento em que o navegador recebê-lo do servidor. Não é necessária uma chamada explícita.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    //todo código aqui será executado
</script>
```

## Executando funções

Entretanto, no caso de ter uma função declarada, o trecho é interpretado e a função é criada, mas ela não é invocada automaticamente:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function f_mostra() {
        alert("Entrei");
    }
</script>
```

Porém, é só adicionar uma chamada posterior à declaração da função para executá-la:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function f_mostra() {
        alert("Entrei");
    }
    f_mostra();
</script>
```

Ou ainda:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function f_mostra() {
        alert("Entrei");
    }
</script>
<!-- ... -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    f_mostra();
</script>
```

## Esperando a página ficar pronta

O problema é que nem sempre é desejável executar o JavaScript enquanto a página está sendo carregada, afinal o navegador pode não ter acabado ainda de montar todo o HTML.

É possível então capturar o [evento que diz se a página está totalmente carregada](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload):

```
window.onload = function() {
  //executado quando tudo na página está carregado
};
```

## Tudo o que disse acima não é exatamente verdade ;)

Existem técnicas e tecnologias que possibilitam, na verdade, o PHP (ou qualquer outra linguagem) executar uma função JavaScript quando o usuário está com uma página aberta, sem uma nova requisição.

Hoje com o HTML 5, temos a tecnologia [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets) que possibilita uma comunicação persistente entre cliente (JavaScript) e servidor (PHP). No entanto, não entrarei em detalhes, pois é um assunto mais complexo.

Comment: Obrigado @utluiz ! Finalmente alguém não ignorou o meu problema e me mostrou como resolve-lo!

Answer (score -3):

É muito simples, basta chamar a função JavaScript pelo echo no PHP.

```
echo '<script>funcaophp();</script>'
```

Comment: Mas isso não é chamar a função JS com PHP; é apenas escrever, com PHP, um texto *qualquer* que, por ventura, será interpretado como JS no navegador. São coisas bem distintas. A resposta aceita trata sobre isso, caso queira ler mais sobre.